# /etc/resolv.conf changed after reboot although NetworkManager.service is masked and not running

Tags: centos, resolv.conf

I'm running CentOS 7.9, why is my `/etc/resolv.conf` changed after reboot ?

Before reboot :

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
search myDomain.lan
nameserver x.y.z.t1
nameserver x.y.z.t2
```

After reboot :

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver a.b.c.d
```

The `NetworkManager.service` is masked and not running :

```
# systemctl status NetworkManager.service
● NetworkManager.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

EDIT0 : `systemd-resolved` is not installed here :

```bash
# systemctl status systemd-resolved
Unit systemd-resolved.service could not be found.
```

Found it : The script `/etc/rc.d/init.d/network` defines the interfaces to give to `ifup` to start in the `interfaces` variable :

```bash
$ grep __sed_discard_ignored_files= /etc/init.d/functions
__sed_discard_ignored_files='/\(~\|\.bak\|\.old\|\.orig\|\.rpmnew\|\.rpmorig\|\.rpmsave\)$/d'
$ cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
$ interfaces=$(ls ifcfg-* | \
        LC_ALL=C sed -e "$__sed_discard_ignored_files" \
               -e '/\(ifcfg-lo$\|:\|ifcfg-.*-range\)/d' \
               -e '{ s/^ifcfg-//g;s/[0-9]/ &/}' | \
        LC_ALL=C sort -k 1,1 -k 2n | \
        LC_ALL=C sed 's/ //')
$ echo $interfaces
bond0 bond0.ORIG em1 em2 em3 em4
$ sdiff -s /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0.ORIG
DNS1=x.y.z.t1                                             | DNS1=a.b.c.d
```

The `bond0.ORIG` file is the culprit.

Comment: perhaps `systemd-resolved` is running ?

Comment: @D'ArcyNader Take a look at my EDIT0.